# Getting something from a web table in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have to get something from a table in a web adress but I couldn't figure it out how. I don't have a proper page to give you as an example but here is how the page will be:

There will be lectures' names at the initial column of the table and each row will include an "add" button with a dynamic numbered id and it changes randomly.(Example button id: add-19872)  I can locate the lecture's names so far but I can't reach their "add" buttons. What I am trying to do is locating these specific buttons with the lecture's name's row location. I mean if the lecture's name is EE231 and it is at the 3rd row, it should locate the button and gives the id of it.

Sorry for the bad english and the expression. 
Have a nice day folks...

Comment: Do you mean a HTML table?

Comment: yes mate sorry I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this Code might help you , but i wrote it as i understand your description of the needed code :

```
    Dim YourHTML As HtmlDocument = Some_WebBrowser.Document
    For Each Your_Table As HtmlElement In YourHTML.GetElementsByTagName("table")
        If Your_Table.Name = "Table Name" Then
            For Each the_TR_Element As HtmlElement In Your_Table.GetElementsByTagName("tr")
                If the_TR_Element.Name = "Your lecture's Name" Then
                    For Each the_TD_Element As HtmlElement In Your_Table.GetElementsByTagName("td")
                        If the_TD_Element.InnerHtml.Contains("Your Button Tag , Example : <Input , <Button") Then
                            'In Above "IF" Condition Make sure you use the tag as showen (<Tag) Not (<Tag> , <Tag/>)
                            For Each InSide_Button As HtmlElement In the_TD_Element.GetElementsByTagName("Button Tag like in Above IF")
                                MsgBox("Button ID is ==> " + InSide_Button.Id)
                            Next
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

and I Recommend you to use WebBrowser for this mission because WebBrowser is helpful in situations like this and if you don't know how to use it , here is a clear example :

```
    Dim Some_WebBrowser As New WebBrowser
    AddHandler Some_WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf the_Document_is_Here
    Some_WebBrowser.Navigate("WebPage URL")
```

and then you will need to add next sub to your Class :

```
    Private Sub the_Document_is_Here(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)

    End Sub
```

and then add the First Code Above in the middle of "**the_Document_is_Here**" Sub , and your Done.

Happy Coding ^^

Comment: Your expression is tremendious. Thanks for the helping mate. You literally "saved my life" and you did it from a bit.

Comment: you're welcome mate ^^